# How to stop setInterval on btn. click and show all divs via JS/JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I've got f.e. 100 shown divs via CSS class and buttons. `#start-showing-divs` to start showing them one by one via a `setInterval` function. I also have a hidden btn, `#stop-showing-divs`.

`#stop-showing-divs` is originally hidden via CSS. I want to use JS to show this button upon clicking `#start-showing-divs`

Later, when a user decides they don't want to show divs one by one any further and clicks on `#stop-showing-divs` JS should stop showing divs one by one and show them all instead and of course hide `#stop-showing-divs` again.

How can I modify the JS to create a function `stopShowingDivs()`? Thanks!

```js
function startShowingDivs() {
  var div_number = 1; /* this number represents total amount of shown divs per each turn */
  var used_numbers = new Array();
  showQuotes();
  var todo = setInterval(showQuotes, 5000);

  function showQuotes() {
    used_numbers.splice(0, used_numbers.length);
    $('.showme').hide();
    for (var inc = 0; inc < div_number; inc++) {
      var random = get_random_number();
      $('.showme:eq(' + random + ')').show();
    }
    $('.showme').delay(4000).fadeOut(3000);
  }

  function get_random_number() {
    var number = randomFromTo(0, 100);
    if ($.inArray(number, used_numbers) != -1) {
      return get_random_number();
    } else {
      used_numbers.push(number);
      return number;
    }
  }

  function randomFromTo(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-all-divs">
  <div class="showme">1</div>
  <div class="showme">2</div>
  <div class="showme">3</div>
  <div class="showme">4</div>
  <!-- more divs... -->
  <div class="showme"></div>
</div>
<button id="start-showing-divs" onclick="startShowingDivs()">start</button>
<button id="stop-showing-divs" onclick="stopShowingDivs()">stop</button>
```

Comment: Use `clearInterval(todo)` should help. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do or what you are looking for.

You can add `$('.showme').delay(4000).fadeIn(3000);` to show all divs when setInterval has been stopped example below.

```js
var todo = null;
var div_number;
var used_numbers;

function startShowingDivs() {
  if (todo == null) {
    div_number = 1; /* this number represents total amount of shown divs per each turn */
    used_numbers = new Array([]);
        
    todo = setInterval(showQuotes, 5000);
    $('#stop-showing-divs').css("display", "block");
    console.log('Interval started');
  }
}

function stopShowingDivs() {
  if (todo !== null) {
    clearInterval(todo);
    todo = null;

    $('#stop-showing-divs').css("display", "none");
    $('.showme').delay(4000).fadeIn(3000);
    console.log('Interval stopped');
  }
}

function showQuotes() {
  used_numbers.splice(0, used_numbers.length);
  $('.showme').hide();

  for (var inc = 0; inc < div_number; inc++) {
    var random = get_random_number();
    $('.showme:eq(' + random + ')').show();
  }
    
  $('.showme').delay(4000).fadeOut(3000);
}

function get_random_number() {
  var number = randomFromTo(0, 4);
  if ($.inArray(number, used_numbers) != -1) {
    return get_random_number();
  } else {
    used_numbers.push(number);
    return number;
  }
}

function randomFromTo(from, to) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
```

```css
#stop-showing-divs {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-all-divs">
  <div class="showme">1</div>
  <div class="showme">2</div>
  <div class="showme">3</div>
  <div class="showme">4</div>
  <!-- more divs... -->
  <div class="showme"></div>
</div>
<button id="start-showing-divs" onclick="startShowingDivs()">start</button>
<button id="stop-showing-divs" onclick="stopShowingDivs()">stop</button>
```

---

Or you could remove the `$('.showme').delay(4000).fadeOut(3000);` from the showQuotes function and then you can add `$('.showme').show();` into stopShowingDivs function example below.

```js
var todo = null;
var div_number;
var used_numbers;

function startShowingDivs() {
  if (todo == null) {
    div_number = 1; /* this number represents total amount of shown divs per each turn */
    used_numbers = new Array([]);

    todo = setInterval(showQuotes, 5000);
    $('#stop-showing-divs').css("display", "block");
    console.log('Interval started');
  }
}

function stopShowingDivs() {
  if (todo !== null) {
    clearInterval(todo);
    todo = null;

    $('#stop-showing-divs').css("display", "none");
    $('.showme').show();
    console.log('Interval stopped');
  }
}

function showQuotes() {
  used_numbers.splice(0, used_numbers.length);
  $('.showme').hide();

  for (var inc = 0; inc < div_number; inc++) {
    var random = get_random_number();
    $('.showme:eq(' + random + ')').show();
  }
}

function get_random_number() {
  var number = randomFromTo(0, 4);
  if ($.inArray(number, used_numbers) != -1) {
    return get_random_number();
  } else {
    used_numbers.push(number);
    return number;
  }
}

function randomFromTo(from, to) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
```

```css
#stop-showing-divs {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-all-divs">
  <div class="showme">1</div>
  <div class="showme">2</div>
  <div class="showme">3</div>
  <div class="showme">4</div>
  <!-- more divs... -->
  <div class="showme"></div>
</div>
<button id="start-showing-divs" onclick="startShowingDivs()">start</button>
<button id="stop-showing-divs" onclick="stopShowingDivs()">stop</button>
```

Comment: Yeah. Exactly a solution I needed. TY appreciated. Can you check down below for 2 more questions please?